# Application refreshes even after using <Link> and react-router for navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

This is the routes.js where all the routes are managed.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link  } from 'react-router-dom';
    import App from './App';
    import Home from './components/home/home';
    import Products from './components/products/products';
    import AboutUs from './components/aboutUs/aboutUs';
    import Careers from './components/careers/careers';
    const Routes = () => (
        <Router>
            <App>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
                <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
                <Route path="/careers" component={Careers} />
            </App>
        </Router>
    );

    export default Routes;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import AppHeader from './components/appHeader/appHeader';
import AppFooter from './components/appFooter/appFooter';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
          <AppHeader/>

          <div>{this.props.children}</div>

          <AppFooter/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And inside my AppHeader i am using Link to redirect

```
<div className="nav-module menu-module">
                                <ul className="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <Link to="/" className={this.getCurrentPath() == 'home' ? "current":""}>Home</Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <Link to="/products" className={this.getCurrentPath() == 'products' ? "current":""}>Products</Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <Link to="/aboutus" className={this.getCurrentPath() == 'aboutus' ? "current":""}>About Us</Link>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <Link to="/careers" className={this.getCurrentPath() == 'careers' ? "current":""}>Careers</Link>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

I have no clue why the application refreshes even after using `<Link>` from `react-router-dom`. Could version of `react-router-dom` be an issue or anything else i am missing.
Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Why are you wrapping Routes with App? try https://codesandbox.io/s/o4nr2xyq3y

Comment: @Liam in App.js i have Header and Footer and all the child routes are supposed to be rendered inside that . any other way to achieve the same thing ?

Comment: Check out the structure I did here https://codesandbox.io/s/o4nr2xyq3y

Comment: @Liam changed my code to match exactly as yours , application still refreshes

Comment: That's weird, why you are using `this.getCurrentPath` inside `className` try to use `NavLink` instead like `<NavLink to="/products" activeClassName="current"> products</NavLink>` and don't forget to import it insted of `Link` from `react-router-dom`

Comment: will it affect the refresh issue ?

Comment: I think so, if it's still refreshing try to upload your code on Codesandbox so I can identify the problem

Comment: is your component react-redux connected component?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168530/discussion-between-yash-sharma-and-liam).

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Yeah i did . so the problem was with the `<li>` tag . There was some script added for that which i wasn't aware of and which  was leading the page to refresh. Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: Glad to help and to know what was the problem.